# How to save pyplot figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to save a pyplot figure to a `.png` file.

Problem is, the graphic displays on the screen, but the file is a blank page!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Pie plotting code from Matplotlib.org 
plt.figure(figsize=(12,9))
labels = defaults.grade
sizes = defaults.grade_pct_of_total
colors = ['yellowgreen', 'gold', 'lightskyblue', 
          'lightcoral','blue','red','orange']
explode = (0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1)

plt.pie(sizes, explode=explode, labels=labels, colors=colors,
        autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=90)

plt.title('Default contribution % \n\n')

# Set aspect ratio to be equal so that pie is drawn as a circle.
plt.axis('equal')

plt.show()
plt.savefig('Default Contributions by Grade.pdf', bbox_inches='tight')
```

Note that

- `defaults.grade` is a list `['A','B','C','D'...]`
- `defaults.grade_pct_of_total` is a series of floats

Comment: save the figure before you show it. you destroy the figure after you close the window, which has to happen before your current savefig command is executed. unrelated advice: you should modify your code to make it copy/pastable instead  of providing caveats and leaving it as exercise to the people who are going to answer your questions.

Comment: @PaulH - thanks....what do you mean by 'making it copy/pastable'?

Comment: The code provided in questions should be a minimal working example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Your code is not because it doesn't define the `default` object. As such, if I copy/paste it into an interpreter, it won't run, and I won't be able to observe the problematic behavior of the code. You recognized this and told people trying to help you how to work around it, but that's not their job. It's *your* job to directly provide the work-arounds in the code so we can copy, paste, and focus on solving problems.

Comment: @PaulH - Well thanks for taking so much time out to set me straight!  And thanks for the focus!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`plt.show()` will clear your canvas as well. Simply remove it or run `plt.savefig` before `plt.show` will fix your problem.